# Issue with MySQL to H2 DDL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, h2, ddl

I have a table created in MySQL that is initiated and it works fine. But I have defined an in memory database with H2 for testing purposes that uses the same DDL to clone the table that I can test my app with.

```
    CREATE TABLE `foo` (
    `fieldA`   BIGINT(20)    NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `fieldB`   BIGINT(20)    NOT NULL,
    `fieldC`   TIMESTAMP     NOT NULL,
    `fieldD`   TIMESTAMP     NOT NULL,
    `fieldE`   VARCHAR(40)   NOT NULL,
    `fieldF`   VARCHAR(40)   NOT NULL,
    `fieldG`   CHAR(3)       NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY `fieldF` (`fieldF`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

But when i try to initialise the table for my tests it spits back this error:

> Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Unknown data type: "fieldF";

That's about as helpful as the error gets. I've explicitly set field F to VARCHAR(40), so what have do i need to do more?

if it helps, I'm creating the table in Spring Boot configuration here:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Import(ImportDataJobConfig.class)
public class TestJobConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public DataSource tlDataSource() {
        return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
                .generateUniqueName(true)
                .setType(H2)
                .setScriptEncoding("UTF-8")
                .ignoreFailedDrops(true)
                .addScript("sql/ve/init.sql")
                .build();
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Edit your question and show the code that you are using to "initialize" the table.

Comment: Are you using the KEY keyword as a synonym for INDEX? If so, you may want to change it to INDEX to see if that helps.

Answer (score 3):

Using h2-1.4.196 MySQL mode, your code snippet gives the following error:

> Column "ID" not found (...)

Your DDL is wrong around `id` and needs to be fixed.

In order to fix the error you're facing, I would suggest:

1. Use the MySQL mode in your JDBC URL like `jdbc:h2:mem:;mode=mysql`
2. It seems your real primary key is `fieldA`, not `id`. Please change your SQL DDL accordingly:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE `foo` (
   `fieldA`   BIGINT(20)    NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `fieldB`   BIGINT(20)    NOT NULL,
   `fieldC`   TIMESTAMP     NOT NULL,
   `fieldD`   TIMESTAMP     NOT NULL,
   `fieldE`   VARCHAR(40)   NOT NULL,
   `fieldF`   VARCHAR(40)   NOT NULL,
   `fieldG`   CHAR(3)       NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`fieldA`),
   KEY `fieldF` (`fieldF`)
   ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
   ```